# How to hide URL in Browser asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, url-rewriting

I know this is repeated question on Stack. But in my case the URL which I am using is passing the querystring details.

`http://servername:82/root/ReportViewer.aspx?Id=/test/base/eg1 &Name=ReportDeatilName & User=783534`

How can I hide the whole query string?

Comment: You could use URL rewriting... look for `http://servername:82/root/ReportViewer.aspx?Id=/test/base/eg1 &Name=ReportDeatilName & User=783534` and redirect/sendto `http://servername:82/root/ReportViewer.aspx?Id=/test/base/eg1` for example

Comment: Duane this URL is generated from NavigateUrl of MenuItem in asp.net in that case also will it work

Comment: I think it really doesn't matter, if you want to "hide it" send it via http post method (even that it's "against" the REST stuff if what you want is to "get" something from the server and not modified de resource...) using a js hidden form

Comment: @PratikGupta It doesn't matter, it will still work.

Comment: [Here's](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-implement-url-rewriting) a simple tutorial on how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can, instead of making a call with GET, you could generate the call using a POST.
So your url will look cleaner (eg: servername:82/root/ReportViewer.aspx), because all the infos are sent in the `<form>`.

Comment: I am not using any GET or POST by myself but using NavigateURL of MenuItems in Asp.net page

Comment: @PratikGupta - all hyperlinks are/make GET requests, whether or not they have query strings/vars is irrelevant (in the context of GET), by default (unless you do explicitly change the type of request, hyperlinks will be GET). The question seems repetitive because its likely no explanation as to **why** is provided. Indio's answer (use `POST`) is perfectly fine. So are `server.transfer` and URL Rewriting. All of these can be used in your case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Server.Transfer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525800%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) from your code behind.

This'd look that you're responsing from the same page. Similar to `Response.Redirect` but simply changes the "focus" on the Web server and transfers the request.

```
Server.Transfer("http://servername:82/root/ReportViewer.aspx?Id=/test/base/eg1 &Name=ReportDeatilName&User=783534");
```

Comment: Abdul i cant use this method as you can my response it's generated from NavigateUrl field

Answer (score 1):

use `Server.Transfer` from your code behind